# TranslateZ is not applied during opacity transition when layer in between has a height specified

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

> This issue is now in the Chromium bug tracker:
>   https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1056331

I have this markup:

```js
const toggle = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("middle");

  if (el.classList.value.includes("fade-in")) {
    el.classList.remove("fade-in");
    el.classList.add("fade-out");
  } else {
    el.classList.add("fade-in");
    el.classList.remove("fade-out");
  }  
}
```

```css
#wrap {
  perspective: 2px;
  perspective-origin: center;
}

.has_height {
  height: 50vh;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

#img {
  transform: translateZ(1px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUSExMVFhUWFxgVGBgXGBcYFhcWFxUYFhYXGhcYHSggGBolHRUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGi0fHx0tLS0tLS0tKy0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIALIBGwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAADBAIFBgEAB//EAD0QAAEDAgMGAwcEAQIFBQAAAAEAAhEDIQQxQQUSUWFxkYGhsRMiMsHR4fAGFEJSI2LxQ3KCkqIHFVOy0v/EABkBAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAwIEBf/EACURAAICAgICAgIDAQAAAAAAAAABAhEDIRMxElEEQTJhIlJxFP/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8Ar2YNwsSM58JHJTfhncu6di/f5LpXj+bPfoVZSMePzQjTfvCBYSnWMEeamM0eQUJVGOiIK8KZ4FPBs21VnhNiVHCXQwf6s+yF5PpCk1HtlDh3GHWOZ05qIEkEjSVpn7KpAwXknlA+qE/ZbT8LnA8wD9FTjkT5oGdD5APMItcc1du2M7RzfEEILtk1f6z0IKw4yX0aWSD+ylouzHJcp5Hr8laPwL2503D/AKT9EP2Efx8kr/Ru17FRmPzguV3x3EI/sScmmeQKZbshwbvVG7rcxvZz0QlYnJLtifFB3reC7jsUG+4z4jqbgDUn6JM4gwAYN5JIGWgVlhdEH8hX0P0Bp0HYAIxVa/aWrWtiYHM6mfFco7ScXQWiDMAaAC5JW/BkvNF5hR7qLCq8NtIBt2mOuiMzaTTl9PC4zWGmjcWmNH4e6VxBsp+3tEFAqmRC532dK/ElSKMClqZjVFD1XyRKmGUSUP244rhqcE00ZaZGu6AehWfq1SQb6Z5eauNoBzmENEn7qhr4Krukbhv0V8bj7IZIy9Mr62KuYfIynj4ICO7Z1Qf8N3ZD/Y1S74HAcwV0eUfZzuMvR6g4hw3TB4qOKqSw2HHLVSdhnatd2KVxNEiLHzTdC2Go1fdbYW5eq9UfJJiEIUrDPJSJgJiOpvfb/VqBs5/vsc8e6HtnpN17H0i2rUbJs9w7OKNCN/qPzRccuajquvK8g9s81NYHBuqvAbkMzoEDBUt90G3HvYdVqaAbSbutEepPFVhjvb6I5MvjpdhcLhKdIWA3v7HM/RBx2IMZ3UK1YnVCe3Lur9LRybbtle15nNWOBpnMoNOnfxTlE3hFgw5jNBNRSrP0QE7EHZVPFFZV8Uk9/D85qVE8SiwoeOIDRKyf6l2k91mj69eSva5kc1n9tNmA34vTi4rN7NpGWrug7pN/5Ec9BzK8XuMNbbz7Rqpfsy57WNvvE31gWLieJNu6tKuF9nSkCXOO6wDhkXKlmKKhzSTuNybmc+oH1ThZuCHQHPsP9LBmVabP2Q2nT3n3dEk/TkqDaGPa4l4yGU/y3b9pjsjsOhqpWEcgPSzR33UOuLhg0EnlP4e6XoGN0G8QDzdm7zJ7IweJJObr+AGfl6J1QrslSqubJBIa0T9r8vVMUNqy0Oc2zictANT2lV2MqFwbTFi+5/5eHip4twkN/iBfo3Pzgd1lwT7RpTkumXlOux0Q4aWyPZFc1ZcVLEm0+8eIaPhA5lHp7ZqNiYcCMjp46KMvj+i8fkf2L2F4JfCbQougF+443g89Ew17T8LgehUXCS7LRyRl0zzV5yawtAOqBjpHulx4gRbPUyEpUeAJWWmjaaejhXl5eQBw5FchSAUW5IGcdTHALjqLf6jsERy85FsKQvWwrCLsb2CVxFFjnFzmNJOZjMwn3JV9O6pjk/tnPnhq0i0OfiunjCifmmKDZMnS/wBFhK3RdulY1s9oDo1A3j1NgPCSnMRiJtoq3AVpqvaOHoR9U0M76nsutKlRwN27Yz7S0IgMkdEq+pJEKdHEj3khDtJufJcpvjrMImGHuTxUGszTA7W8ylt8ZKdS54JVxvmkAY1FJtZLl11wnmk2aoKamcJXEUvdJi5zXt+9ymWiQEjXRXbL2buS/NzrdBoOgTGJwnvMtMHyFvmT4qwpAALrQCZTM2Uv6gdFF8aiJ4TZYCLtGkz4C6+gbdp7wLfyyxv7WCSeE/RUg6MyjYJrpcBoJJPM5+seK7Vqy6P7GOjG5/RL4ZsknmB4C584XHOuTrkOgufMeaoYGsPU3qr3n+IMeFh5koVSpMjPeMeAMAeJ3ihYJ27TceMN9XFBpPyPV3YQgQzWqgnkD3gfZIOcXuk6Rb0+ZKnVNo5eZz+aWe6Gxq4/b0HmmjLY82gSwVNXOLW9BafElbH9KYNtEOrOg7jC6OLhlbgMgqZ7R/hptFmMB6nMrR0sCTQiS0bvvdOalORWEPszlHbT/auqOdLqjyXchOXn6K5kWhZMYazoyDj65+S0mznn2TeMKGdKk0dWCW2mMLwXCVEjVQOhkmlcGXioMzgrrdUATK65cXtEgOOyQHBHUAFpCY05t+ydwYkO/MhP0STirPZbPiPAE+JTh2YyfiyvwnuVZ4gju4x8k22tBuq2u6HTwAd2cn8UJAdGYnvkulM5KI08UN6AUFuJioSTbIqpOJ3ajs4iyVxGM3jnz8Oa0I+m4d0tmbIbjY81Qfo3bPtqJYfiYSOrdD6rQkAjNJmRR5kpepYolR8EpSq9ZNpEzEn5LglDpVLpiFmzVC4bfNN0cwgP80XBPlCBjcKLqkKTjolK1cC5zWjCK3atf3jbNZ3GOvOh9Fc7RpmCQVnqzidYC0hirWxMaye64+h6HzR8Nhi8wO6taOzQPiJJSlkUTccbkZ9zPcI4T8voUu1luw+Z9PNawYFmjQuPwYgW1lLnRr/nZjqwMn8/M0xsjAmrXYzQXKu8RswElWX6T2fulzznMBU5U1ojLDT2EpYCa5MWH2j0Vrine48F0CIg2VlQwoAnVVO3MIKrTTcLO4GDbgdFLtm7roomYdm5DSHTw80TBDdpgaiQh7P2d7EbjZIkmSUdxiR1Wcnorif2zpcg1K8fxcbSYGQNx1twQMTjGtzKQp4vePvVS2f6iJ8Yt4IjhlVtBLPG6TLmlUBggyDkpysxR2iabnEEEF1mmRI/sDkD6q5w+0GuvlqQfy6U8TWzUM0ZaHwVIJOjjWGAHXOWd4zCZa71UXFrsrGSfR2VEFdGaG4oGOOV5sloFJ7ucKjd8lfbKH+Ani5NaJz6M9jHDfeOCbwlffwzTPvMJafDJL4+n77jz+RQtgtJD2aEie32VoOyM0VWPHvk8j4KrILg6BpBK0u1cM1gIvJS+zcKBSIOb7+sKjl4onGLkyo2JjXUHhzfEcRqvo2z9oNqs3m9tR1Xz40LnimMFtB1E7zc+GhWnsxRuMYZGWqQNXQj7rtLaIe33huuIB4j7KFUEaiDkVKytNHKdUSOKc/dAKpBhx1KHWqugoAtn1eChgq0PEqhbizGueeiZw+1Gam/mmhM0VfESIHiqrFOH8kWlifcaeIlVW0MVv5/glbowC2nigIaDAPiUmRAjX5Fcw93bx6XTdGkCS6ZusSkkUjFs7s+jugE6hOAqD8hyK6udu3Z1xVKjm9dS3/VQebrspDOtFk7sjEhp3TrkfkkJsvUakHzW4OmSyRtGqFabC6r8bTc5zREQbqw2fVa4Bw1HnwQsWQHA8VdHLZT4nD7pPSVTYx5bc2mSOYkj5FanG0pB6LH/qXalMMpUGiXNDi48C45eUwtw/JCnuD2U2NxMqtc/Qf7Jilg6jved7jM5OZHIFTL8O3Qk87/AGXUSWF1bdf6WGysA6qwVNyo8Awd1riDGkgWzCtv2tFw3XUTTOhhwEjK5/LrOYf9S1aQ3aLnsbMwHFonjDTCuNm/qvFvBnEVQeG+TboVz5IPuzacVpOxjFUaQcxxqQW70NFxvZSOHBHZUnxCjtyajKFWoB7VzXbxiC5ocQxxA1ib6pbDP0XNNaOrFLY6wrphBDlPeUy46Vf4E/4BzJVEVdYM/wCFnj6rMujLKrFNuep9FDYUDf4lwHlf1UsYfUquwz3NqSDAIIHNwMlVxbJZdIltUh9Xdmbxb5lMsHoq7CS6u4utAnxP4VYyjL3Q8XVlRtMAVDGvqlKdPecFLEVQ4ucdHdgEfZjJeT/UT3yV3qJzrci4pIheQgsKm8rkfZ2KqJvJIzhB9jOZPkiNdK4SdOSNhUewD8K3ge68cDTz3R4qcmbohKdv2FL0MPcBTAsIEf7LO4okvbGROi0WLEsbAtEnne6z0j2jRrJ6CAuuPRxS7A1g8ODZkk5DVXLKe60N/JSOBpbz3VDldrfDMqwqFQyPdHRjWrZ0CRCiwyB+XUQeag18E9Z7gj5eanRWydVdfqoPfkuvPoigsmChA3Xt35KAsU0gbLTYeK3XFk2N+jloqjGyASN4DejlosU2pukHgVZ7a2y1tRlZl2lu6RrY3HWJV4b7OXKq6LP9S4kUqDqmsW5lfIt8vqBxvJk89StL+qNq+3fILvZtZ7oy985khZXBVPeJubQumEaOaUtDOOqucZc4k8NB4JAvRcQ+ShgKpJtt2yMotCsWmWmCguZwQy6EmKzc4razcSQ9o3QGtYGzO6GgACfBRp5qk2FRcJebAiBz5q3BuFxzik6R3YpPTY3vLspcvXQ4qNHVZdGs3iFd4N00m9FjW1WkfJafZrv8TI0HzWcsPFGYT8mKYx1/FUb3bhdJyO83gG5npc+SucUbqg2lRLnOziNNbwtYHszmWhjZFbedUeSLkcjr9U5i68MeWkSGmL6wqHAsIZIMST+eSO2p/qE85VpY7dko5KVCZf8A44H8jvSrXYNQQ4kgTAVXWpXI0zHzCZaY7rc1aoxB+LsvRUHEKXtm8R3VAeoUZ5qXF+yvN+jRNqt4juF4VhxHdZzjddAKXCvYc79GhdXbxHcLxrt/sO6oCRrEqFSpGvmjhQc79GuNSWMAOh7yshtCvu1CGmblo8bSrTDYoNoSc2gxOVzdZvBHfq3yEu/O6vFUiEpW/wDTX0w1jQwOENEZhdL25bw7qmNMHXml68cfVRWNP7LPLX0aBtZv9h3CC+q0OBkQbZ9vRUVFoJufVMOYIzujjS+w5m/ot312x8Q7hc9u3+w7hVppWhKYsRqhY17G8rW6Lz9w2PiHdQ/cNn4h3CzzXjijbwA5rXEjPO39FwcQ3+ze4QalYR8Q7qrpvbKnU9UcdBy2K42TMEJSmwMHM5/RP1KTmtDi0hrj7pymM4VRWfcrrj0cUuwb3SZUmtUWhRqVNAmZCligQvNY5cIPJMC32Lif+GfD6KzdnZZZjoM9leU9ptIGcxw1XPkhu0dGOeqY82q3iO6mKzeI7hU7ng3Gq9vKfGdHMXf/ALe/O3n9Fotnu3abW8Gn1QQYzRKbvRc+STkqZTHFJg62aSDJDwM92ezgnKoQGODSbG7SEYzWTopsLhnOZDYME8Z/LorcA/gPNM7BcPZuHB7vMAp4lWlNptEIwTVlX7EsLS+IJi3HNCxeFLaoZb3m7wnv9VaYqjvN3fEHmMoSW0S7cZUzLI7FEZWDiQOz3gDLz+ii3Av4DsVa0HvtbNMws8jH4IzjsObAwD0ciDDu/wBgVdmJUvzJHIHGUVTCOcfsUCps586/9pK0IomZlTNPQo5GgeNMz+0MM8YcQSfe0GTY+qrdjUHHecLfxuCef0WxxTw2naDId6Kp/T1KaRsSC9xtloFVyaiSUU5ABRfxHYodbCEi5y4D7rQsoLn7MDTupchXwRm6OFM5webfujeydxHb7q8/baQFBuGaTFj4J8gLHRT+zdNneU/NCxWHJEE66D7rQ/s+V/yLLzsLGaOTYeGqMpTwN/i8YH/6RH4Y/wBv/H7rRDBDgF04Max5J8pniMo7D/6v/HPzUmsI/l5fdaj9oJymOi47CD+vyT5RcQv+oj7QClAEQWG9rAR0WKxeFe1xDmmeQkeBC3+NogtY5wy90nyB9Ek8Bx3Sd1+h0dHHmuxO0mjhdptMwzg7KCgtaZW0qYaYc5sHkJB68FT7WwYZUPB1/kR+cUDK1sqJlFIjJBe5MCBRKbihEqdMpMaLHDtJAM+Sl7B39vL7p+hs9zWgTPRG/ZO4Fczns61DRonNm05qNOk5v8vJWIwdvdvzJiEs7EUpLYLozvb7rkuzpoW9oCfiyUq1cU2ueQMiBOUlEoijvD3HdAbeKZ2lghUpljae6HXJJ7I8kmgatGV2NiT7V4gAPG+AeWfkR2Wjpi14S+N2X8FRoLXMEjdEjxOqsdmbQa5oJaQ64I3cuYHAreR3tE8etMVfB8EvWpAs5RCvnV6bh8BI1O7HzzVZjqTdyGjdFxBmYU4yZRoDsYzTIz3Lc40THs5OQ8EIAUnbwyAk3zClU23vQGsEefotO7tCVDDMIeCk4RayYw9cEAkx9T1ClicaGn+x5Cyxbs1SAMwpiQAlcTSyBkbxDZi17ZqwftBoE7t/JVe1cV7RkZH4hwkJxu9mXVCzaJcXMHwgQO0x2RdgYYmlDYMPcCNZlBL/AGYaxrSDVAqcYLh6e6VP9MNBNVheZFQO90iLtzuOIhXyfjolD8ixFMReZ5A/NK137ph0HWBJItN1a4hrACCJGf5CAardzeZTDhlFh4niudNl9AsBSZUkyfd6+iPU2YQZ+ECbiI8eaDSrMF3B1Em02APSQvYj2Zbve1e4c/PRJ+VhoN+0cM788l5+Cgg+9e0Ag3Q8FjqLW2cTJADf5T4wEavcyypUBPxCREC2WnRL+VhoLT2eP7O8Y+ii/BAWB8QPuFKLTvzpd0Dnop1cUXQAQ0NAuDOSz/Kx6A/sTMxEjjPkvOwBAzBvwLjl1UTg2OcHB0EXkTcx1Q6+z775e6OthlrKdv2Gge0cKfZkkCB1GccQsxjKW83mLc5Gq2T3s3HTUY4EQBMknj1uszWDd4h2ot1/2XofEk5Qaf0cHyopTTX2L7M2kHN3KpG/JbewcNPFCx2BD2lpPvAkgnXh9FV7To+8SOY8ErhNqObZ1288x4rqOUSry0kEQQl3FW2JNOoM76XuqypQI5pGgSd2PhDVrU6Yze9rfCb+UpFa/wD9O8EDWdWeDFMQ2AY33cxlA9VPLLxg2UxR8pJGxfgqbTG+EWng2EAyOycq+xmHAAkaifOEocS3/wCRw/6PsvJuTPUpABiH5GmN3XMg6Juhsyk0b4aATxB9Ch0WE2DTwufNNupuiCQTFgrNE7A0WN3rC456einXe9uTJGpH10UxRI+IkdLyg19oU2WLjPCCUqCwtCsCL9iR66oxoze3h9UozENdefLznRM0niLG3IyhoQvXeWiNxx/5RbnJKAw72RIni0DwkBdxrXm1ov8AyuRllwUaNMbsSCdLwE6GTr4dsw6OUW62CizAUaZygmdTmmg0nIxnYanqkG4Bpk75J5nyuhANU2Um3gnrJQ/ZhzpDWuHIkHsoYdjmkhreWYPdEDns+OowXsIJIHWUUAU4RjhcRyS37ShI+GR+cbrmIxbv4nOMmn1TWAcY98RGpSqgBYjDAua9pALZHUEZHyKoqlIUapqb8TYgWkT8lo8W8WLYN8uKA/BB9ywN52J8wqxnrZNx3oWJa4WfY2kG3dCpYaMnz0Tn7ZoAaXQOy7SwbJgC3FTKEcQzeI3wCBlMFQxDC4iBbgUatSAcGtaIA6Ixw7c8+EoATOGYLbrQeQQsRhPaD4oAvAFu2qcO9BtPLP7Lga4iPhIQAlXw53NwNLhxyg8YlLDZbxcOgm3OPBXdCkRmQhuDXEkxPL6p2Apg2+yBFyYjXyCP+4OXLKQfIogqQOXFQpNBuRc+KQC4qtmCCJzEC02zVPtHDBsNJBvY8tJ5rQYyqxjZc0QeQKz+2sY1zgADlaBwJvbIrq+M2n+jl+RTX7RV4v8AqPzus7XeASDf0VxW2iG3gzp9yZ9EbA4Cnimue47pBsGQd0H+wteQumUktnNGDeigY4HgUcMjMKzr/p9zcnMI5ktP0Sm65h3XAc7giOMjJCnF9MHCS7QqcKH1A0CLNnxAlav9P7RfQJo04LLmHaO1Mi+az+Eqe8+qBb4W9NPRX2xA0NLy0lxnoAOfFQzbVHRhVOy/xWN3mxUb/wBs+qDS2oAI98odHFBwu0eJBlcIbwauXxOqy9pUxrA8b90YOgT5pZvuiDc+BJ66I29YABIDxxQmJEpfFYYvzDYHl1lGay82lHaTxt4QgCtwuz2nmBfM7vSE/wC13cjlwgeqXftDdqbtt06XA7nNEqupkaQgRCpUa8glrCRxv5rlak0gwBvZg5DyUqdNou2/opgHWO1+10DF6WJLRBBJ4xbzQ8SXvbuw5o4geKf9uQ3InoIQnYhgzkz8tEAJYVjmm5junA+m6YblYuz89Ut++03bdSnmkuaIt8vuhgcp5DckeB+aHWcACHAu6zHkoVMM4fyHcqTGnU5JAcw9JjuAjmjUBpHQxbzUfcGZsu1MTTIgOBjg6EAexuGLryMoj5ylMKyoD7wB5j6ZqFPFVN6N23UFPRvRvEDoSD3T6AjVNObtdbkV2xPugxGqKKbRlfzQcQ90/DN9D9kgCto9eiG926Zjhmu08Q0a39FGtQbUM7xjkTM/nJIA5faSFU16Jc7eY4t/0jLyAhExOGqU7h0gnIm4nidUzRpHdBIy6X5p9ALNpOHxeSeNQCR36KMjlPBLuxB3oAnp+XQMkHB8tLS5p5CPEE2SFfZ+HB3m/EOBJg+Ke3HOEENI4EQpNoxmGt6JqTXRlxT7M1U2VQflTvySbtjVmOmkA0aw6MuIK11akDBBmeYTFCnH8Y5k5rfIzPHEzNDZlV7CKlxa1vwop/T9MthzJHI2V/WoM4weI+ahTkGIBHUrPmzXiimP6fpboZBA5G4Xaf6fbTbEucOdv/qruvhW2Jz6wF1haBl80vOXsPFGabRZlBHddGBZz7q7NR82ZYqW+f6o8h0dwJne/NF3En/EenzXl5A32NURYeHoqSvVd7Zw3jHCTC4vJxEOi5IN7DNZ+qYe6OK6vLSBljgnnie6tcDmev0Xl5YkNBcc8hogkZZIe4CRIHZdXkwQGnTG6bD4uCZcfeZ1+RXl5JiDYoXCXIuF1eTEgdfJL0qY4DMaLy8gY8WCRYLtdojJeXkgO7PaL2Ci43d1+i8vIQiLLuumWCy4vIYCbXEvve+qnisiuryGMCz4J1nPXNHoLy8gA70jiD7wXF5CALSYM4EyUvthx92/8h6FeXkvsYmBOfL1TYaIy1K8vIYxrDmW3S2KeQbEhdXkfYj1N54nJANR3E915eTA/9k=");
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle()">Toggle opacity</a>

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="middle">
    <div class="has_height"> <!-- REMOVE HEIGHT HERE -->
      <div id="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where the `.wrap` has a `perspective`, the `#img` has a `translateZ` and on button click the image can be toggled to fade in and out.

For some reason during the fading sequence of the `opacity` the `translateZ` will not get applied when an intermediate element (`#middle` or `.has_height`) has a `height` applied to it.

I don't really understand why this is happening and I have made a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Niwilai/pen/bGdBmmw) to explain this problem.

In the codepen  when you remove the height of the class `has_height` it will just work fine. But when you add the height back in it will `snap` and apply the translateZ only after it has finished fading in.

Also it is worth mentioning that it is not only happening when you apply a height to `has_height` or `middle` but pretty much all methods that create a `height`-layout (Flexbox, Table, position: absolute with top, bottom, left, right 0)

*Note: Interestingly this works fine in latest Firefox but not in Chrome*

*Edit: Added Chrome and Webkit tag*

**Edit 2: I have made a GIF of what is suppose to happen: [See here on Gifyu](https://s5.gifyu.com/images/Feb-26-2020-14-44-41.gif) this is how it works on latest Firefox.** The image is big from the beginning (due to translateZ) and fades in and out and stays the same size.

Comment: add your code inside the question, don't use a link to an oustide source https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just to get a clear view of what your issue is, is it  about `translateZ` not animating with opacity in chrome? I noticed that its also not working for Firefox too, opacity is the only attribute that gets animated.

Comment: The translateZ should not be animated, it should be applied before opacity is fading. As you can see though the translateZ is applied AFTER opacity transition has finished. So opacity transition is disabling the translateZ for some reason.

Comment: @supersize, I was playing around with your Codepen, I noticed that `wrap` perspective CSS attribute can also be the reason for this weird behavior, if you keep the height attribute for `middle` and remove perspective from `wrap` it will work, this seems to be a conflicting behavior in Chrome, anyway I will keep investigating this!

Comment: `perspective` is a required attribute to make translateZ to take effect. So it will work because translateZ is not applied at all when removing perspective. This is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a parent element that has `perspective` property set. Now any child element which has `opacity` less than `1` does not render `translateZ`. Not sure, whether we have to consider this as a bug in chrome or webkit browsers.

So if you need to use `opacity` and `translateZ` then add the `perspective` to the same element which has `opacity`.

In the below example I have added `perspective` to the `.middle` element that handles `opacity`.

```js
const toggle = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById("middle");

  if (el.classList.value.includes("fade-in")) {
    el.classList.remove("fade-in");
    el.classList.add("fade-out");
  } else {
    el.classList.add("fade-in");
    el.classList.remove("fade-out");
  }  
}
```

```css
#wrap {
  /* perspective: 2px; */
  /* perspective-origin: center; */
}

#middle {
  perspective: 2px;
  perspective-origin: center;
}

.has_height {
  height: 50vh;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

#img {
  transform: translateZ(1px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle()" style="text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer">Toggle opacity</a>

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="middle" class="fade-in">
    <div class="has_height"> <!-- REMOVE HEIGHT HERE -->
      <div id="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not correct. The question is about the translateZ not being applied during the transition of opacity. As you can see in your example of the code it will also jump from small to big and vice versa (hence translateZ not being applied before the fade-in/-out)

Comment: But having you said that I can remove the visibility because it is not necessary for this question. (I edited the visibility out now to not cause any confusion)

Comment: Got it, I just updated the answer please have a look.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, unfortunately I need the setup in my original question. I specifically created a minimal example in hope that someone can explain why this is happening and has an alternative solution with this setup. Your answer does change the structure.